# Real time Export of excel 2003 fields to MS word 2003 fields

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel-2003, microsoft-word-2003

I am a practicing radiologist. We enter patient information such as Name, date of birth, number (patient ID), referring physician's name, and date of the study at the front desk in MS Excel 2003. Is there any way to export this data in real time to MS word 2003, on a network laptop? If possible, can somebody help me with a script or show me how to do it? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I believe if you copy the data you require in Excel and then use the Paste Special option in Word you can paste it as a link so changes to the excel document are mimiced in the Word document.

EDIT:  In fact [this](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/share-data-between-excel-and-word-healthcare-forms-HA010067091.aspx?queryid=3c0a21d32e5d49b7b44de02ea68c1ec2&respos=5&CTT=1) microsoft page should be right up your alley.

EDIT 2 :  [This link should still work here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/word-help/link-or-embed-an-excel-worksheet-HA010120810.aspx)  The aim is basically to copy the data in Excel and then use the Paste Special functionality to paste a link to the data.  This can be updated periodically or when the file is opened.  Hope this helps and thanks @pnuts for finding the dead link.